# Как правильно сделать wall.get?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Мне нужно получить много(несколько тысяч) постов с определенной стены, с условием "размещены ранее определенной даты". Думал запускать цикл, в котором получать по 100 постов через `wall.get`, используя `offset`сдвига, внутри сделать проверку даты и заносить результат в массив.

Но возникла такая проблема: за то время, пока выполняется мой цикл(а вдруг он будет выполнятся продолжительное время) на стене могут разместить еще несколько записей и тогда в моем массиве возникнут повторяющиеся записи, да и вообще всё поломается. Как с этим можно бороться?

*Проведенное исследование:*
Еще думал получать записи не через `wall.get`, а через `wall.getById` и получать посты с конца, по одному т. е. начинать с определенной даты и идти к текущему моменту. Но этот способ выглядит гораздо более медленным, да и нужно каким-то образом получить пост-точку отсчета (то есть последний пост, сделанный до определенной даты), и я не знаю как его можно получить.

Comment: Вообще, wall.get работает довольно быстро. На сколько я помню, можно без проблем делать 3 запроса в секунду, т.е. получать 300 постов в секунду. Но на всякий случай, да, можно просто удалить дубли.

Comment: @Илья а есть ли ограничение по частоте запросов у vk api?

Comment: Да, были какие-то. Увы, не помню уже точно числа.

Comment: @Илья, сейчас попробовал запустить цикл на 100 итераций, с запросами wall.get - все работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Делайте wall.get в цикле - а потом просто удалите дубли.